# Delay while receiving data via BLE in Android app

Tags: html, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, phonegap

I have created a hybrid app using Cordova. It receives data from peripherals via BLE. After receiving the packets, I displayed them. In iOS app, it is getting displayed instantly, without any delay. But, in Android app, delay is observed. I'm able to display the data, only when I do page navigation. I don't understand this problem. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: How much delay? 16 ms or 1 second? What is your connection interval? Is it delay in the Bluetooth communication itself or is it your UI that is slow to update?

Comment: Instead of mentioning it as a delay, I'd say that it is only updating the values, after page navigation(main page -> navigating to a new page -> coming back to main page). I'm not sure,whether it is due to Bluetooth or UI. This happens only in Android app, not in iOS app. I have used document.getElementById.innerHTML to display the values

Comment: That seems certainly that something is wrong with your UI code. You should at least show it since otherwise it's impossible to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: var value=(data[1]+ (data[2]<<8))/10; document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=value;

Comment: <div class="card left" id="one">
    <img src="./img/img.png">
    <div class="card-footer">
     <p id="card_title">value</p>
     <p id="id">0</p>
    </div>
            </div> UI used to display the value